# Apple watch event detection

Tags: event-handling, apple-watch

Are anybody aware of any event api for the apple watch ? I'm looking for detecting events like on/off wrist events do determine if glances should be displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are not any events other than the simple ones declared in the various interface controls, like willActivate, didDeactivate, button taps, etc..

There are rumors that the next version of WatchKit this Fall will include more capabilities like being able to run some code on the watch itself, so maybe it'll be possible to have more event notifications once that comes out, but who knows.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm really hoping for is some kind of event on the phone which the accompanying app can subscribe to. The idea would be to tailor the behaviour on the phone depending on the status of the watch.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be nice.  I'd like events for my app regarding watch orientation, like whether it's being held up towards the sky or is being looked at like normal.  Unfortunately, in this first iteration of the SDK, Apple is only offering simple events like notifications on activates, page changes, or button taps.